# What kind of flower is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification, flowers

I was in my garden a few days ago and found the flower shown in the pictures.
Can anybody tell me what this flower is?

Location: Germany / northrhine westfalia
Date: February 2017
Season: Winter

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Edit]:
My neighbour thinks it is a Anemone hupehensis (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_hupehensis), could be right.

Comment: Probably Gossipum sp.

Comment: You mean a cotton plant? This was the first thing I thought about, but I haven;t planted it. Maybe I have to look nearby my garden if there are more them. Thank you.

Comment: @SanjuktaGhosh Did you mean [*Gossypium* sp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossypium)? however I didn't knew it could grow at cold places as Germany.

Comment: I'm not sure. It just looked like one.

Comment: @LStrike Seemingly the white things are not flowers but fruits having wind-dispersed seeds. Do you have some more close-ups; especially the [calyx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepal)-like thing at base of fruit ([picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z70n6.jpg)), close-up of seed-like things in the cottony zone, and the stem nodes and internodes, branching, stem-tip, it would greatly help.  And if you could collect the leaf (seemingly all are hardly dried) and soak it in water and expand it to reveal the leaf shape, it would help.

Comment: My neighbour thinks it is a Anemone hupehensis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_hupehensis), could be right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is [*Anemone hupehensis*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemone_hupehensis). We have this species in our garden, and the seeds and dead leaves look very similar to the ones in your picture. The leaves are large,jagged and palmate and they have beautiful flowers in the summer/autumn (I've seen red, pink and white). The fruits/seeds also look very distinctive and cotton-like. The species is originally from Asia/China.

Here is a picture of the fruits/seeds:
[image]
(Hard to find good ones, this from Instagram page [http://www.ipopam.com/tag/höstanemoner](http://www.ipopam.com/tag/h%C3%B6stanemoner))

Comment: Looks very similar to the one I have in my garden.